# How can I pass URL parameters from the source through a wordpress bridge page to the destination?

Tags: wordpress, url-parameters

Here's my setup: I am collecting information inside of Messenger and passing the data to a pixeled WordPress bridge website via URL parameters: [www.mysite.com/?first_name=fname&last_name=lname](http://www.mysite.com/?first_name=fname&last_name=lname).
This bridge website then will automatically redirect to the destination site on a different domain ([www.mysite.otherdomain.com](http://www.mysite.otherdomain.com)) that has the form that I want to be filled with the information collected in Messenger.

Here's my question: How can I automatically pass the URL parameters from the bridge page (mysite.com) to the destination site (mysite.otherdmain.com)?

Answer (score 0):

You can run some javascript to change the destination links:

something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(a){
    a.href=a.href+window.location.search
})
```

This will look through all the links on the page and will add the url parameters  (`window.location.search`) onto each link

You may want to refine this to:

1. check that there is not already a querystring on the destination url
2. only make the change if there are query parameters present
3. limit the urls that are changed (if for example you do not want to change menu items on the page

Comment: Hi Ian! Thanks for your response.
So to clarify, on the destination page is a form that has fields that need to be filled, with their IDs and content for the form being sent via the URL parameters.  I don't want to change URLs on the destination page.  I just want to pass the information from the source through the WordPress bridge page to the destination page.  Can I do this via javascript on the page that will instruct the page to redirect to the destination page with these parameters as part of the URL?

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of your code (perhaps a simplified version of the form you are trying to send) @Mackensie

Comment: also, do you want to pass just specific url parameters on or just specific ones?  What do you want to happen if there is a url parameter that matches a form field name?

Comment: Yes it is this page that is the destination URL: https://nwmaids.launch27.com/?w_cleaning
So I am asking most of the questions from this form in Messenger first (except address, city, state, time of booking and credit card information), then when they hit the submit button in Messenger, it will send the answers via URL parameters, but first going through a WordPress bridge page that redirects to that destination URL (The reason for the bridge page is to have a pixel be fired as I can't add the pixel to the destination URL).

Comment: why not fire the pixel when the form is submitted?  This should be fairly straightforward, especially if you are using something like Google Tag Manager

Comment: The way this pixel works is that the URL needs to be on the same domain as the thank you page to track a conversion.  Because the form page is not on the same domain as the thank you page, I have to put a bridge page first that has the same domain as the thank you page.